# Python: OSError with Augmentor

Tags: python, augmentor

```
2023-04-11 16:12:33,568 ERROR    [Errno 5] Input/output error
2023-04-11 16:12:33,570 ERROR    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/me/bot/modules/verification.py", line 342, in onMemberJoin
    p.process()
  File "/home/me/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/Augmentor/Pipeline.py", line 391, in process
    self.sample(0, multi_threaded=True)
  File "/home/me/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/Augmentor/Pipeline.py", line 362, in sample
    with tqdm(total=len(augmentor_images), desc="Executing Pipeline", unit=" Samples") as progress_bar:
  File "/home/me/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tqdm/std.py", line 1093, in __init__
    self.sp = self.status_printer(self.fp)
  File "/home/me/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tqdm/std.py", line 336, in status_printer
    getattr(sys.stderr, 'flush', lambda: None)()
OSError: [Errno 5] Input/output error

2023-04-11 16:12:33,570 ERROR    <class 'OSError'>
```

I am presented with the above statement when doing the following:

```
p = Augmentor.Pipeline(folderPath)
p.random_distortion(probability=1, grid_width=4, grid_height=4, magnitude=14)
p.process()
```

(Error on p.process line).  folderPath is a valid, writeable folder (the image existing in there was generated successfully). The folder has valid permissions.

It is running on a cloud server that I'll ssh into on occasion as a discord verification bot.  It was previously running on another cloud server with no issues for years but I moved everything over to a new server and now am presented with this.

- Old OS: CentOS v8
- New OS: Rocky v9
- Python v3.8.2 (same on both)
- Augmentor v0.2.12 (same on both)
- discord.py v1.5.0 (same on both)
- psutil v5.6.7 (same on both)